# Converting row names to data frame column

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to be able to access b0.e7, c0.14,...,f8.d4. But right now these are not in a column, but are the "row names". How can I have the row names be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and b0.e7, c0.14,...,f8.d4 to be it's own column. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
df=as.data.frame(c)
df = subset(df, c>7)
df
        c
b0.e7  11
c0.14   8
f8.d1  10
f8.d2   9
f8.d3  11
f8.d4  12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. The first line assigns a new column that is just the current row names of the data frame.  The second line resets the row names to `NULL`, resulting in a sequence.

```
> df$new <- rownames(df)
> rownames(df) <- NULL
```

Which should result in

```
> df
#    c   new
# 1 11 b0.e7
# 2  8 c0.14
# 3 10 f8.d1
# 4  9 f8.d2
# 5 11 f8.d3
# 6 12 f8.d4
```

And you can reverse the column order if needed with `df[, c(2, 1)]`

Comment: I liked your answer before the "another option". You'll have to add a `row.names = NULL` in there if you want to extend it to an answer that works with a `data.frame` with many columns (unless you want to add each column manually) at which point... :-)

Comment: Right you are, rolled it back

Comment: For the curious, Richard's answer here is actually faster than the `cbind` approach.

Comment: When trying this using mutate in a pipe chain, `df %>% mutate(name = rownames(df))` fails (no name column is added), but calling `x <- rownames(df)` then `mutate(name =  x)` has the expected result. Any idea why mutate can't seem to perform rownames?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the fact that `cbind.data.frame` can make use of arguments from `data.frame`, one of which is `row.names`. That argument can be set to `NULL`, meaning that a slightly more direct approach than proposed by Richard is:

```
cbind(rn = rownames(mydf), mydf, row.names = NULL)
#      rn  c
# 1 b0.e7 11
# 2 c0.14  8
# 3 f8.d1 10
# 4 f8.d2  9
# 5 f8.d3 11
# 6 f8.d4 12
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this as well.

```
rows = row.names(df)
df1 = cbind(rows,df)
```

Comment: Please consider adding a bit of explanation.